# Assign function to variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call function dynamically based on variable and the variable has the function name ,  for example

```
var fun =function1(1,2)
```

after sometimes **variable fun** can have function

```
fun= function2(2,3)
```

its just an example to explain my scenario

and then I want to call it from my html

**html**

```
<button ng-click="{{fun}}>call</button>
```

fun can have function1  and function2 sometimes

Comment: dont use {{}} if you want to access a variable. just use the variable name

Answer (score 1):

Because functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript, we can pass them around like we would with any other variable.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs43zxfq/1/) example that alternates `f1` and `f2` when you click on `Change Handler`.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div>
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fun()">Show Name</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeClick()">
          Change Handler
        </button>
        <br>
        <h3 ng-show="clicked">You did it {{name}}</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){

    function f1() {
        $scope.name = "Chris";
    }

    function f2() {
        $scope.name = "Harry";
    }

    $scope.fun = f1;

    $scope.changeClick = function() {
      if($scope.fun === f1) {
        $scope.fun = f2;
      } else {
        $scope.fun = f1;
      }
    };

    $scope.name = "Default";
});
```

In the example above, `changeClick` alternates the value of `fun`

Comment: what if functions have parameter too?

Comment: No problem -- you would still change them the same way, regardless of whether they have parameters or not. Just make sure you pass in the parameters when you call the function in `ng-click`. For example `ng-click="fun(param1, param2)"`

Answer (score 0):

dont use {{}} if you want to access a variable. just use the variable name

```
function foo() {
    console.log("executing foo");
}

$scope.fun = foo;

<button ng-click="fun()">call</button>
```